# Mongo db query for multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb

I have a Mongodb Json which look like this

```
{
    "_id" : "5b862ebecebe455a1744",
    "userId" : "111",
    "courses" : [
        {
            "stateName" : "statge 1",
            "courseId" : "1453",
            "courseName" : "Program Training 1",
            "duration" : 1,
            "lag" : 0,
            "courseType" : "1",
            "transitionType" : "onComplete",
            "scheduledStartDate" : ISODate("2018-07-27T16:23:14.000+05:30"),
            "scheduledEndDate" : ISODate("2018-07-27T16:23:14.000+05:30"),
            "courseProgress" : 0,
            "ASD" : ISODate("2018-09-17T23:18:30.636+05:30"),
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "stateName" : "stage 2",
            "courseId" : "1454",
            "courseName" : "Program Assessment 1",
            "duration" : 1,
            "lag" : 0,
            "courseType" : "2",
            "transitionType" : "onComplete",
            "scheduledStartDate" : ISODate("2018-07-28T16:23:14.000+05:30"),
            "scheduledEndDate" : ISODate("2018-07-28T16:23:14.000+05:30"),
            "courseProgress" : 0,
            "score" : 0
        },
        {
            "stateName" : "stage 3",
            "courseId" : "911",
            "courseName" : "Program Training 3",
            "duration" : 1,
            "lag" : 0,
            "courseType" : "1",
            "transitionType" : "onComplete",
            "scheduledStartDate" : ISODate("2018-07-29T16:23:14.000+05:30"),
            "scheduledEndDate" : ISODate("2018-07-29T16:23:14.000+05:30"),
            "courseProgress" : 0,
            "score" : 0
        }
    ],
    "userStatus" : 1,
    "modified" : ISODate("2018-09-12T11:49:47.400+05:30"),
    "created" : ISODate("2018-09-12T11:49:47.400+05:30"),
    "completionStatus" : "IP",
    "currentState" : {
        "courseProgress" : 0,
        "stateName" : "statge 1",
        "courseId" : "1453",
        "courseName" : "Program Training 1"
    }
}
```

I want to find a query where condition is. Please help, as I am new to mongodb 
courses.transitionType = oncomplete
(PROGRESS<100||(PROGRESS==100&&ASD exists false))

And print Result something like this which contain these below data

```
{
    "_id" : "5b862ebecebe455a1744",
    "courseData" : {
        "userId" : "4688",
        "courseId" : "1476",
        "courseProgress" : 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use an aggregation with a [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage and a [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) to format your result.

The tricky part of your request is that you want an answer by course, but 1 item of your collection contains many courses. So first, you can use the [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage to separate every course

```
db.[CollectionName].aggregate([
{
    $unwind : '$courses'
}
{
    $match: {
        'courses.transitionType': 'onComplete',
        $or: [
                {
                    'courses.courseProgress': { $lt: 100 }
                },
                {
                    'courses.courseProgress': 100,
                    ASD: { $exists: 0 } 
                }
        ]
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        _id: '0',
        courseData: {
            userId: '$courses.userId',
            courseId: '$courses.courseId',
            courseProgress: '$courses.courseProgress'
    }
}
```